# C# Ton of Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, console-application, text-based

I'm coding a Text-Based RPG currently, everything was going fine but then I guess I did something that destroyed my code, I'm not sure what I did but I now have 242 errors. My code is in a GhostBin File (Just a website where you can paste your code to show others):

https://ghostbin.com/paste/qp9k8

If anyone could find a reason as to why my code is all broken, help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Anthony.

Comment: The question should be self-containing, and at least you could mention the errors, or at least some of them.

Comment: If you check the error list, what's the first error you see?

Comment: Please post at least the first few errors on the error list and maybe describe what you were trying to do in the most recent change to your code. Also, are these build errors or do they happen while running?

Comment: according to http://converter.telerik.com/, -- line 30 col 13: this symbol not expected in Block

Comment: At least you have a class inside your Main method, which is not proper. And that class has random code outside methods. So I guess the "something" you did that "destroyed" your code was copypasting things randomly?

Comment: You can't define class inside `main`

Comment: @CurseStacker thank you, I've found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line code

```
public class Inventory {
```

You can not define a class inside Main function.